# How do i fix "property or indexer 'Control.Right' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"?

Tags: c#, winforms

So i'm trying to make a pictureBox fly down from the left side. That worked fine. Then i try to make a new but it flys down from the right side but i get this error: property or indexer 'Control.Right' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

```
    public int enemy1SpeedTop = 4;
    public int enemy1SpeedLeft = 7;

    public int enemy2SpeedTop = 4;
    public int enemy2SpeedRight = 7;


    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // 15 miliseconds delay
    {

        //works fine
        enemy1.Left += enemy1SpeedLeft;
        enemy1.Top += enemy1SpeedTop;

        //doesnt work
        enemy2.Left += enemy2SpeedRight;
        enemy1.Right += enemy2SpeedTop;
    }
```

Comment: I would imagine that Right is a field derived from Right = Left + Width - 1. Since it can easily be derived, you have to set it by applying alterations to either Width or Left, depending upon whether you expect placement to move the control vs. resize it - it's basic math really.

Comment: @MarkRabjohn did you mean this? enemy2.Right = enemy2.Left + enemy2.Width - 1; still gives me the same error

Comment: No, you can't set Right directly, but you can derive a value for Right from Left and Width. e.g. without resizing, a control could have it's right hand side positioned as 'Left = RequiredRightPosition - Width + 1' - if you expect to resize the control, you'd leave the left alone and vary width instead i.e. 'Width = RequiredRightPosition - Left + 1' - rearrangements of the same formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.right) says

> The `Right` property is read-only. You can change this property value
>   indirectly by changing the value of the `Left` or `Width` properties or
>   calling the `SetBounds`, `SetBoundsCore`, `UpdateBounds`, or
>   `SetClientSizeCore` methods.